# Use Google Cloud PubSub emulator from Java

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-pubsub-emulator

I've setup `Pubsub.Builder` with root url pointed to local PubSub emulator (`localhost:8036` at my case). It seems to be working, I see that emulator is receiving my test pushes, but gives me error 400 Bad Request.

Publish code:

```
auth = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY)
         .createScoped(PubsubScopes.all());
client = new Pubsub.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, auth)
         .setApplicationName "test"
         .setRootUrl("http://localhost:8036/")
         .build();
msg = new PubsubMessage().encodeData("{\"a\": 1, \"b\": 2}".getBytes());
req = new PublishRequest().setMessages(Arrays.asList(msg));
client.projects()
  .topics()
  .publish("projects/GCLOUD-DEFAULT-PROJECT/topics/test-topic", req)
  .execute();
```

In emulator console output I see following (that's for very basic `PublishRequest`):

```
[pubsub] jan 27, 2016 9:03:20 PM com.google.cloud.pubsub.testing.v1.FakePubsubGrpcServer$2 operationComplete
[pubsub] INFO: Adding handler(s) to newly registered Channel.
[pubsub] jan 27, 2016 9:03:20 PM com.google.cloud.pubsub.testing.v1.NettyUtil$HttpVersionDecider channelRead
[pubsub] INFO: Detected non-HTTP/2 connection.
[pubsub] jan 27, 2016 9:03:20 PM com.google.cloud.pubsub.testing.v1.NettyUtil$HttpJsonAdapter channelRead
[pubsub] INFO: Invalid input: Expect message object but got: "\u001f�\b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000�V�M-.NLO-V���VJI"
[pubsub] com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Expect message object but got: "\u001f�\b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000�V�M-.NLO-V���VJI"
[pubsub]    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.mergeMessage(JsonFormat.java:1099)
[pubsub]    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.merge(JsonFormat.java:1075)
[pubsub]    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.merge(JsonFormat.java:973)
[pubsub]    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$Parser.merge(JsonFormat.java:201)
[pubsub]    at com.google.cloud.pubsub.testing.v1.PubsubJsonGrpcAdapters$PublisherAdapter.handleRequest(PubsubJsonGrpcAdapters.java:231)
[pubsub]    at com.google.cloud.pubsub.testing.v1.NettyUtil$HttpJsonAdapter.channelRead(NettyUtil.java:94)
[pubsub]    at io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelReadNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:83)
```

Seems that default PubSub client uses different protocol, but I don't see any way to configure it.

How can I use `com.google.apis:google-api-services-pubsub` library with local emulator?

Answer (score 2):

The emulator does not require or handle authentication or authorization; I'm guessing that's where the problem lies. Can you try passing `null` as the last parameter to the builder?

Also, it appears that Gzip compression must be explicitly disabled. Please set this on the builder:

```
.setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {
  @Override
  public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?> request) throws IOException {
    request.setDisableGZipContent(true);
  }
})
```

Comment: Note: Gzip-encoded requests are supported as of sdk release 96. See https://cloud.google.com/sdk/release_notes .